# Fluentd grep + output logs

Tags: amazon-s3, kubernetes, devops, fluent

I have a service, deployed into a kubernetes cluster, with fluentd set as a daemon set. And i need to diversify logs it receives so they end up in different s3 buckets. 
One bucket would be for all logs, generated by kubernetes and our debug/error handling code, and another bucket would be a subset of logs, generated by the service, parsed by structured logger and identified by a specific field in json. Think of it one bucket is for machine state and errors, another is for "user_id created resource image_id at ts" description of user actions

The service itself is ignorant of the fluentd, so i cannot manually set the tag for logs based on which s3 bucket i want them to end in.
Now, the fluentd.conf i use sets s3 stuff like this:

```
<match **>
  # docs: https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/out_s3
  # note: this configuration relies on the nodes have an IAM instance profile with access to your S3 bucket
  type copy
  <store>
    type s3
    log_level info
    s3_bucket "#{ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']}"
    s3_region "#{ENV['S3_BUCKET_REGION']}"
    aws_key_id "#{ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']}"
    aws_sec_key "#{ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']}"
    s3_object_key_format %{path}%{time_slice}/cluster-log-%{index}.%{file_extension}
    format json
    time_slice_format %Y/%m/%d
    time_slice_wait 1m
    flush_interval 10m
    utc
    include_time_key true
    include_tag_key true
    buffer_chunk_limit 128m
    buffer_path /var/log/fluentd-buffers/s3.buffer
  </store>
  <store>
  ...
  </store>
</match>
```

So, what i would like to do is to have something like a grep plugin

```
<store>
  type grep
  <regexp>
    key type
    pattern client-action
  </regexp>
</store>
```

Which would send logs into a separate s3 bucket to the one defined for all logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that user action logs are generated by your service and system logs include docker, kubernetes and systemd logs from the nodes.
I found your example yaml file at the [official fluent github repo](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset/blob/master/docker-image/v1.2/debian-s3/conf/fluent.conf).
If you check out the folder in that link, you'll see two more files called `kubernetes.conf` and `systemd.conf`. These files have got `source` sections where they `tag` their data.

The `match` section in fluent.conf is matching `**`, i.e. all logs and sending them to s3. You want to split your log types here.
Your container logs are being tagged `kubernetes.*` in [kubernetes.conf on this line](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset/blob/4c01c443f8cfefba17d683fa10501ca775943578/docker-image/v1.2/debian-s3/conf/kubernetes.conf#L13).

so your above config turns into

```
<match kubernetes.* >
@type s3
# user log s3 bucket
...
```

and for system logs `match` every other tag except kubernetes.*

Comment: "user action logs are generated by your service and system logs include docker..."
well those, but not only them, i would like to have debug logs, error logs catched by code and output by structured logger to be in different bucket from record keeping actions, like user_id created resource image_id which would be gdpr friendly, and need to go into a separate bucket. so the source of both types of logs is the same (structured log library i use) but destinations would be different based on a key in the log for example

Comment: i edited the question the better reflect the problem